# Sticky footer text issue - CSS

Tags: css

I am having a bit of trouble with a sticky footer (a footer that stays on the bottom of the page). The actual text in the footer will float to the bottom of the page but the background will not. I have reviewed some of the top suggested questions but they do not match my issue. For example:

[Sticky Footer failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271378/sticky-footer-failure)

was having issues with the footer staying on the bottom when viewed from a smaller screen. Or another user had the html markup all weird. I believe I have followed the correct html as evident below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="header_container"></div>
        <div class="line_seperator"></div>
        <div id="header_text_container"></div>
        <div class="line_seperator"></div>
        <div id="outside_container"></div>
        <div id="footer_container_new"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

And I believe I got the css correct as evident below:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    background:url('../images/background3.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}

#outside_container {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom:-120px;
}

#footer_container_new {
    background: #09C;
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However I still get overlap from one of my forms as evident below:

http://www.verney.ca/pbd2014/registration/index.php

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: P.S. line_seperator contains no actual information, its just a div to break up the content. Its styled in no way.

Comment: Try changing your pixels to % as % adjusts to the size of the screen. Hope that is what it is?

Comment: Hey Brendan thanks for the comment. It was I did not clear both in the footer container as suggested by James below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `clear` to the footer container.

```
#footer_container_new {
    background: #09C;
    min-height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. How would I go about creating that little bit of space between the elements though? On the registration page the form is basically touching the footer

Comment: To add a space between the form and the footer try making the following changes `#outside_container{min-height:100%; /* Remove this line and add the below styels */, width: 100%; overflow:auto;}`. Now remove the empty `div` with `padding:10px;` and to adjust the space between the form and footer adjust the `margin-bottom` of `#outside_container` as you need.